# how to filter name/value pairs under a registry key by name and value in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to get a feel for the idioms to use in PowerShell.

Given this script:

```
$path = 'hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Extensions'
$key = Get-Item $path
$key
```

I get the output at the bottom of this question.

I'd like to get output of the properties (the name/value pairs under the `$key`) where I can filter on both name and value.

For instance, filter to list all the Extensions that have:

- name like `xls*`
- or value like `*\MSACCESS.EXE`

Or an exclude filter: exclude all names like `doc*`

Fir the first filter, I'd want a result like this:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
xlsx                           C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                                                                                 
xls                            C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                                                                                 
mdb                            C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE                                                                                                              
mda                            C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE
```

This is the original output of the script:

```
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
Extensions                     rtf  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.rtf                                                                                                         
                               dot  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.dot                                                                                                         
                               dotm : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.dotm                                                                                                        
                               dotx : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.dotx                                                                                                        
                               docm : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.docm                                                                                                        
                               docx : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.docx                                                                                                        
                               doc  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE ^.doc                                                                                                         
                               xlsx : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                                                                                 
                               xls  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                                                                                 
                               mdb  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE                                                                                                              
                               mda  : C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE
```

**Edit**

I solved part of the problem: getting a list of Name/Value pairs. It uses [PSCustomObject](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/24/pscustomobject-save-puppies-and-avoid-dead-ends/):

```
$namevalues = $key.GetValueNames() | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ Name=$_; Value=$key.GetValue($_) } }
$namevalues
```

(How should I wrap that code?)

Any help with the filtering would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a much more clever way to enumerate registry values (found it [here](http://9to5it.com/enumerate-search-registry-key-values-with-powershell/)). And it's more powershell-way IMO.

I've turned it into a one-liner:

```
(Get-ItemProperty $path).psobject.properties | 
   where {$_.name -like "xls*" -or $_.value -like "*\MSACCESS.EXE"} | 
      select name,value
```

**Update:** As noted in comments by @mklement0, you should be careful about properties `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, and `PSProvider` within the `psobject.properties`.

Comment: Thanks. I never heard about the `PSObject` property as it does not show up with `Get-Member`, but apparently it is hidden because it is present on any PowerShell object. Learned a great new thing today. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Nicely done; @JeroenWiertPluimers: To make `Get-Member` show normally hidden members, use the `-Force` switch. Yes, `.psobject` is available on any object in PowerShell and is a rich source of reflection.

Comment: As convenient and concise as this solution is, there is a pitfall: PowerShell's registry provider automatically adds its own properties to the collection of properties reported in `.psobject.properties`, namely `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, and `PSProvider`, which means that a wildcard expression that filters by name can accidentally include them, or, worse, if values by the same name happen to exist on the key (even though unlikely), the provider properties override them.

Comment: @mklement0 Nice addition. But I believe this issue is an affordable price for a convenience.

Answer (score 6):

A two part answer.

We start with the `$key` from the registry:

```
$path = 'hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Extensions'
$key = Get-Item $path
$key
$key | Get-Member
```

Since `$key` is a [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx), you cannot get the name value pairs out directly.

The first step is to create a list of [PSCustomObjects](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/24/pscustomobject-save-puppies-and-avoid-dead-ends/) with `Name`/`Value` pairs. The `Name` comes from the [GetValueNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames) piped through a [ForEach-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx). For each of those Names, we get the `Value` through [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue):

```
$namevalues = $key.GetValueNames() | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject] @{ 
      Name = $_; 
      Value = $key.GetValue($_) 
    } 
  }
$namevalues | Format-Table
```

An alternative for the first step is to use the [Select-Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vishinde/archive/2012/08/27/expandproperty-in-select-object.aspx) using [-ExpandProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176815/powershell-select-the-values-of-one-property-on-all-objects-of-an-array/5176941#5176941) as explained by [Scott Saad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916/scott-saad):

```
$namevalues = $key | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject] @{ 
      Name = $_; 
      Value = $key.GetValue($_) 
    } 
  }
$namevalues | Format-Table
```

The second step is to filter the `$namevalues` either by `Name` or by `Value`.

The [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347549.aspx) has some pretty cool [Comparison](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operators that [accept regular expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730947.aspx) like `match`, `notMatch`, etc.

To make the code more readable, you can [wrap lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command/3235993#3235993) (thanks [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/)!) either use the backtick (`) or take advantage of the places in the PowerShell syntax where it does accept line breaks, like after a pipe (|) or opening brace ({):

```
$matches = $namevalues | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match '^xls' `
    -or $_.Value -match 'msaccess.exe$' 
  }
$matches | Format-Table
```

The result is as wanted:

```
Name    Value                                                                                         
----    -----                                                                                         
xlsx    C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                       
xls     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE                                                       
mdb     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE                                                    
mda     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE
```

Answer (score 2):

A **more robust PSv4+ alternative** to [montonero's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036422/45375):<sup>[1]</sup>

```
Get-Item $path -PipelineVariable key | ForEach-Object Property | ForEach-Object {
  $name = ($_, '')[$_ -eq '(default)'] # translate '(default)' to '' for API calls
  if ($name -like 'xls*' -or ($value = $key.GetValue($name)) -like "*\MSACCESS.EXE")
    { [pscustomobject] @{ Name = $name; Value = $value } }
 }
```

- `-PipelineVariable key` stores the `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` instance returned by `Get-Item` in variable `$key` for later use in the pipeline.
- `ForEach-Object Property` enumerates the target key's value names (via the `.Property` note property that PowerShell adds to the output `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` instance).
- Inside the `Where-Object` script block, `$_` then refers to the value name at hand, and `$key.GetValue(<valueName>)` is used to retrieve the associated data.

  - **Important**: In the `.Property` array, PowerShell translates the **default value name**, which is the *empty string* (`''`) at the API level, into name `'(default)'`; thus, if `$_` is `'(default)'`, you must translate it to `''` before calling `$_.GetValue(<valueName>)`, which is what 
    `($_, '')[$_ -eq '(default)']` does.
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` then constructs and outputs a `[pscustomobject]` instance with `.Name` and `.Value` properties reflecting the matching value's name and data.

---

[1] [montonero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036422/45375) is concise and works well in the case at hand, but it comes with caveats:

**PowerShell's registry provider automatically adds the following additional note properties** (members of type `NoteProperty`, as reflected in the output from `Get-Member`) containing *metadata* about the targeted registry keys **to the `[pscustomobject]` instance that `Get-ItemProperty` outputs**:

- `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, `PSProvider`

These **can interfere with filtering based on `.psobject.properties`** in two ways:

- Using wildcard matching against `$_.Name` can accidentally include these properties.

  - E.g., `$_.Name -like '*drive*'` would match the `PSDrive` property, even though it isn't actually part of the registry key.
- Perhaps more hypothetically, if the registry key happens to have values of the same name as these provider properties, the provider properties *shadow* (override) these values.

  - E.g., if the key has a `PSPath` value, `$_.Value` will report the *provider* property value instead.